# Auto scroll sticky headers with respect to grid item clicks

Tags: android

I am working with sticky headers referenced from https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders.  I have a grid view of multiple categories at home screen when i click on any of its item it should auto scroll sticky header of other fragment to that selected category. 
[image: first grid screen]

[image: 2nd screen]

how can i handle this smooth scroll with respect to categories. 
Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: How your data is coming means is it sorted by category?

Comment: yes , and i have a bean class for list of categories and its item.

Comment: Check answer, it is my logic you should do something like this

Answer (score 0):

Check position of category and listView smooth scroll to that position

```
 private int findPosition(int category)
    {
         int position = 0;
         for(YourListClass object:YourList)
         {
            if(object.category == category)
            {
                 position = YourList.getIndexAt(object);
                 return position;
            }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it should be YourList..indexOf(object);